# From Dusseldorf airport to Bochum Ruhr University by public transport

Tags: public-transport, germany, airports

How to get from Dusseldorf Airport to Bochum University campus, by public transport, train or bus?
I plan to go there early October 2015.

Comment: Google maps was able to provide a public transit route, you might want to search there.

Comment: @cdkMoose Google's coverage of public transport is in Germany unfortunately not very good. In this case, Google does not seem to know the subway line in Bochum and suggests to take a taxi from the main station to the university.

Comment: Understand it's not the best, but certainly a starting point

Answer (score 5):

You take the train from Düsseldorf Airport to Bochum Hbf (main station) and change there to subway line U35, which will take you to the university. There are 3-4 trains per hour and the subway departs every five minutes, or even more often during rush hours. If you have a few minutes to spare, you might prefer the regional trains from Düsseldorf Airport to Bochum Hbf, as they are slightly cheaper (13.70€ vs 19.00€), but almost just as fast as the long distance trains.

You can search for available connections using the [German Railway's trip planner](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/en).

Comment: A slight addition: Using the long distance trains is even more expensive, as it will require the OP to also buy a ticket from Bochum Hbf to the University, *and* for the SkyTrain to the main airport railway station. This should cost roughly 4 Euros extra. In the regional train ticket for 13.70 Euros, these trips are already included, and the ticket can be bought on the platform of the SkyTrain to the airport main railway station. If I recall correctly, the machine does not accept credit cards, though, and doesn't accept bills above 20 Euros for this trip either.